# Calculate Inventory in Stock Cost

Tags: dax

I’m having a bit of trouble calculating the Inventory in Stock cost. As silly as it sounds, here’s the scenario:

Item |  Inventory Bought (units) | Order Number |  Amount Paid $

SKU 1   1000        Order 1                                    1111

SKU 1    1000      Order 1                                    2222

SKU 1   1000     Order 1                                    3333

SKU 1   1500      Order 2                                    2000

SKU 1   1500   Order 2                                    3000

SKU 1    1500    Order 2                                    4000

SKU 1    1500   Order 2                                    5000

SKU 1    2000   Order 3                                    1500

SKU 1   2000    Order 3                                    2500

SKU 1  2000 Order 3                                    3500

(for simplicity, there is only 1 SKU in this table, but in reality my table has many)

As you can see, each order has multiple entries in the table, and these duplicates need to be disregarded (not summed). What I mean is, in my example, there are only 3 orders:

Order 1:          1000 units -> Total Paid: 1111+2222+3333 = $6,666 => Cost/unit = $6.66

Order 2:          1500 units -> Total Paid: 2000+3000+4000+5000 = $14,000 => Cost/unit = $9.33

Order 3:          2000 units -> Total Paid: 1500+2500+3500 = $7,500 => Cost/unit = $3.75

And here comes the interesting part. I’m told that we had a certain amount of sales (the rest is still in stock), and I’m asked what was the cost we paid on the inventory that is still in stock. To make it more clear, let’s do 3 scenarios that are linked to the above table.

Scenario 1: Total Sales = 2750 units

=> Stock Left = 1000 (Order 1) + 1500 (Order 2) + 2000 (Order 3) – 2750 (Sales) = 1750 units

From which order can this quantity (1750 units) be: Order 3 (because it is smaller than the quantity we bought in Order 3, and we assume that sales are in chronological buying order i.e. first sales are from order 1, then order 2, then order 3 etc)

=> Inventory cost: 1750 * 8.73 = $15,277.5

Scenario 2: Total Sales = 1500 units

=> Stock Left: 1000 + 1500 + 2000 – 1500 = 3000 units

=> This quantity is from the last 2 orders (as it is bigger than the last order, but smaller than the sum of last 2 orders): 2000 units from Order 3 and 1000 units from Order 2.

=> Inventory Cost: 2000 * 8.73 + 1000 * 8. 62 = $26,080

Scenario 3: Total Sales = 500 units

=> Stock Left = 1000 + 1500 + 2000 – 500 = 4000 units

=> This quantity is from all 3 orders (as it is bigger than the sum of last 2 orders): 2000 units from Order 3, 1500 units from Order 2 and 500 units from Order 1.

=> Inventory Cost: 2000 * 8.73 + 1500 * 8.62 + 500 * 8.51 = $34,645

I’d really appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: Why not handle the deduplication upstream in your data source or with some ETL?

Comment: Kyle, I've just posted an update to the question. I can't deduplicate the data because what I get as duplicates are just the orders' quantities, and that's due to different payments for the same order.

Comment: So why not just aggregate them to one row ie Order 1 has 1000 units sold for 6666? All the measures in a row in a fact table should be at the same grain.

Comment: Anyway I'm protesting too much, your data is what it is. But you should strongly consider separating out these two measures into separate fact tables since they're at different grains.

Comment: I see your point and this approach would help, but I was trying to create a measurement in DAX that would work on the data as it is.